# Overriding Copy/Paste function

Tags: acumatica

I have a extension table in Sales order and the values are not updating while copy past a sales order. Is there any way I can override the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the fields you want to copypaste are enabled. Disabled fields are not posted.
You can use Save as Template option in Copy Paste menu to review values that are being copied.

You should not need to override the copy/paste function to just have your custom fields copied.